# XQuery Recursive Function Call for Inner Tag

Tags: recursion, xquery

I'm trying to prepare an XML file to parse it JSON and its context is such as:

```
<user_manual>
  <embed-language_part id="SL14686180">
    <language_part id="1" role="-" lang="de">
      <embed-user_manual_part id="1">
        <user_manual_part id="1" role="-" document-type="IU">
          <embed-chapter id="1">
            <?ecls-start-embedded-resource resource="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a30660983"?>
            <chapter id="1" role="-" toctitle="yes" footrowtitle="no" type="security">
              <embed-title_module id="1">
                <title_module id="1" role="-">
                  <title id="1">Sicherheits- und Warnhinweise</title>
                </title_module>
              </embed-title_module>
              <embed-section id="1">
                <section id="1" footrowtitle="no" role="-" toctitle="yes">
                  <embed-section id="2">
                    <section id="2">
                      <embed-title_module id="2">
                        <title_module id="2" role="-">
                          <title id="2">Eisschale</title>
                        </title_module>
                      </embed-title_module>
                    </section>
                  </embed-section>
                  <embed-title_module id="3">
                    <title_module id="31" role="-">
                      <title id="3">Bevor Sie das Gerat in Betrieb nehmen</title>
                    </title_module>
                  </embed-title_module>
                </section>
              </embed-section>
            </chapter>
          </embed-chapter>
        </user_manual_part>
      </embed-user_manual_part>
    </language_part>
  </embed-language_part>
</user_manual>
```

I wrote an XQuery script regarding to my expectations first (assume that `$doc` is document, `$matnr` is 22333),

```
declare variable $doc external;
declare variable $matnr external;
<dmContainer>{
for $language in $doc/user_manual/embed-language_part/language_part
let $lang_code := data($language/@lang)
for $embed_chapter in $language/embed-user_manual_part/user_manual_part/embed-chapter
let $objectid := data($embed_chapter/processing-instruction('ecls-start-embedded-resource'))[1]  
let $fileattr := string($objectid)
let $filename := translate(substring-after($objectid,'resource='),'&quot;','')
let $postfix :=  substring(tokenize($filename,'_')[last()], 2)    

let $name := concat($matnr, '_', $postfix)                              
 return (element {$lang_code} {    
    attribute title {data($embed_chapter/chapter/embed-title_module/title_module/title)},
    attribute language {$lang_code},   
    attribute name {$name},        
    for $section in $embed_chapter/chapter/embed-section/section
        return <section title="{data($section/embed-title_module/title_module/title)}"></section>
})
}</dmContainer>
```

This returns:

```
<dmContainer>
   <de title="Sicherheits- und Warnhinweise" language="de" name="223333_30660983">
      <section title="Bevor Sie das Gerat in Betrieb nehmen" />
   </de>
</dmContainer>
```

Return contains the chapter element and its first section's title for the JSON but I have to add this one to all sections (the sections included by sections too).

According to the input XML the sections can have another sections (one or more) recursively. You can look the example by searching it deeply. The question is that how i can add these sections to my output with a proper recursive way(i mean not just the child level one level two children are included too) , i searched for some examples recursive functions of XQuery but i couldn't get any one.

Expected output:

```
 <dmContainer>
   <de title="Sicherheits- und Warnhinweise" language="de" name="223333_30660983">
      <section title="Bevor Sie das Gerat in Betrieb nehmen">
      <section title="Eisschale"/>
      </section>
   </de>
</dmContainer>
```

How can I get all sections?

Comment: Please have a look at how to post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org). If you want others to answer your question specifically to your code, make sure they can directly run the code by copy-pasting it: no external variables, what's `$language`? Some proper indentation for the XML would also help at understanding the problem.

Comment: I wrote on the question $doc is document name and $matnr is 22333. The others are derived from $doc, $language is derived too. So what is the problem ?

Comment: Seems I failed at putting everything together, you're right. I removed my downvote, as the code works after some modifications. I still do not consider this a _good_ question, though. Why do you declare external variables, instead of putting the content there? No need to describe what to pass into them (and this description isn't really correct: it seems `$doc` shouldn't contain the "document name", but the document). This is a matter of showing effort, also stripping out unnecessary parts (like the whole construction of the language and name attributes, which is not relevant for the question.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake about this one, and thank you for your edits.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want *all* sections in that chapter (in document order), go with the `descendant-or-self-step`, abbreviated `//`.

```
for $section in $embed_chapter/chapter//embed-section/section
    return <section title="{data($section/embed-title_module/title_module/title)}"
```

If document order doesn't work out for you (eg., first the title of the current section, then all subsections on the current level, no matter if they actually precede the title), you will have to write your own function traversing the tree: a function that gets the current section, returns the title, and recursively calls itself for the direct subsections (if there are any).